# Linux Command to append two TXT files

Tags: linux, command-line

I have two txt files : a & b. What linux command would I use to append b to a without appending the columns names for cust_name | cust_no?

a.txt contains

```
CUST_NAME|CUST_NO
John|100
Mary|101
```

b.txt contains

```
CUST_NAME|CUST_NO
Jane|102
Karen|103
```

The append command should ouput

```
CUST_NAME|CUST_NO
John|100
Mary|101
Jane|102
Karen|103
```

Comment: You can use append operator >> and then a output file name

Answer (score 3):

Use the `tail` command to skip the first line of the second file. Use the `>>` redirection operator to append the result to the first file.

```
tail -n +2 b.txt >> a.txt
```

`+2` means to start at line 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
cat a.txt; sed 1d b.txt
```

or

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' {a,b}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have identical line, you can do something like this in addition of @Barmar

```
cat *.txt | sort | uniq > result.log
```

Comment: That isn't a bad approach, but it does result in the content of `result.log` being sorted -- which may, or may not, be a problem.